# ZF2 functions on each page load

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm looking to migrate some of my projects from our custom framework into ZF2. In our framework we have one 'global' controller what sets up the page layout, header, gets any data from the database that's needed on every page, and then all other controllers for separate pages extend of of that.

What's the 'Zend' way of doing this? E.g. on every page I need to run a query `SELECT html FROM dbcms.adverts` and display the `html` field on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a `ViewHelper` that gains access to the Database. This access is done by having any DB-Access-Tool you want (`TableGateway`, `Doctrine2`, `DbAdapter`, etc..) and pass this into the `ViewHelper`.

The `ViewHelper` then would simply return the HTML-String. And inside your Layout and/or View-Scripts you'd use the `ViewHelper` in the likes of `echo $this->myHtmlViewHelper()`.

Comment: Thanks :), I'll take a look at those classes now.

Comment: @Sam how are you tought's on using a event http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/a-list-of-zf2-events/ for such tasks? I am facing a similar problem and while I'am using a  view helper I tought a event could simplify a few things.

Comment: @cptnk Completely depends on the actual use-case / requirements. There's tasks where an `EventListener` may be more appropriate than a `ViewHelper` (personally I find it hard to think about one now though).